# Send image on any text using Slack bot

Tags: python, slack

I'm trying to send an image to user when 'message' event is triggered.
I managed to send an image BUT even though I have a condition that makes bot not to reply on own messages, it sends image over and over again

```
BOT_ID = client.api_call('auth.test')['user_id']

file_name = "./cards/card3.png"

@slack_event_adapter.on('message')
def message(payload):
    print('MESSAGE HAPPENED')
    event = payload.get('event', {})
    channel_id = event.get('channel')
    user_id = event.get('user')
    
    if BOT_ID != user_id and user_id:
        print(f'user_id: {user_id}, bot_id: {BOT_ID}, channel_id: {channel_id}')
        res = client.files_upload(
            channels=channel_id,
            initial_comment="Here's my file :smile:",
            file=file_name,
        )
```

[image]

I'm 100% sure that im sending only one message to the channel and somehow i get two or more

Comment: `if BOT_ID != user_id and user_id:` seems wrong. Could you try changing to `if BOT_ID != user_id:`?

Comment: I added it because sometimes user_id was none